# a well-defined algebra isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

How to prove that this map is well-defined, surjective and 1-1:

$$1\otimes a+i\otimes b+j\otimes c+ij\otimes d \mapsto a \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix} + c \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} + d \begin{pmatrix}
0 & i\\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers and this map gives the isomorphism $\Bbb{H\otimes_R C }\to M_2(\mathbb C)$

Another question: Why a map that maps a basis to a basis must be an isomorphism?is there a proof or a theorem that say this? Should I use that theorem here?

Comment: I've edited the title to something more descriptive. You can change it again if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you ask: "Why a map that maps a basis to a basis must be an isomorphism?" Well, remember these are vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ in particular. So the correct statement is that a *linear* map that maps a basis to a basis is a (linear) isomorphism. This does not by itself guarantee that they are isomorphic as rings too. Okay, on to the problem.

**Well-defined**

$\mathbb H$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra with basis $\{1, i, j, ij\}$. We then know by "extension of scalars" that $\mathbb H\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ is a $\mathbb C$-algebra with basis $\{1\otimes 1, i\otimes 1, j\otimes 1, ij\otimes 1\}$. But that's the same as saying that an $x\in \mathbb H\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ can be written uniquely as
$$
x = 1\otimes a+i\otimes b+ j\otimes c+ ij\otimes d
$$
with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb C$, so your map $\varphi:\mathbb H\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb C)$ is well-defined.

**Homomorphism of algebras**

It is easy to see that $\varphi$ is linear ($a,b,c,d$ are scalars). What remains is to show $\varphi(1)=1$ (which is evident) and $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$. Using linearity of $\varphi$, we only need to check this on base vectors. For example:
$$
\varphi(i\otimes 1)\varphi(j\otimes1)
= \begin{pmatrix} i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0&i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}
= \varphi(ij\otimes 1)
$$
and so on. (This amounts to showing that the matrices generate the quaternion group.) Alternatively, we could take the product of two general elements and do it all in one go without appealing to linearity.

**Bijective**

Now we just need to show $\varphi$ is bijective. Since $\varphi$ is a linear map, we only need to show that the four matrices are a basis of $M_2(\mathbb C)$. It's obvious that another basis for $M_2(\mathbb C)$ is
$$
\mathscr B = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \right\}
$$
In particular $M_2(\mathbb C)$ is $4$-dimensional over $\mathbb C$. And now we can prove linear indepence by writing our matrices as (column) vectors over $\mathscr B$ and take the determinat:
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} 1&i&0&0\\0&0&1&i\\0&0&-1&i\\1&-i&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
= 4 \ne 0
$$
Done! We conclude that $\varphi$ maps a basis to a basis, so it is bijective and thus an isomorphism.

Comment: I can not see in the proof of well definedness, How what you did prove well definedness ... could you please explain more?

Comment: I do not understand how extension of scalars makes you by 1 ? could you please explain this?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3399387/620957). Alternatively you can regard the structures as $8$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-algebras. In that case a basis is $\{a\otimes b \mid a\in\{1,i,j,ij\}, b\in \{1,i\}\}$, which is a basic theorem on tensor products.

Comment: Let me ask, when we write $1\otimes a+i\otimes b+j\otimes c+ij\otimes d $ (the left hand side of my map) what basis of $\mathbb C$ we are using and why?

Comment: (1) We regard $\mathbb C$ as the scalar field, so we use no basis. $q\otimes 1$ where $q\in\{1,i,j,ij\}$ are the basis vectors of $\mathbb H \otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$, which we multiply by the $\mathbb C$-scalars. (2) $\mathbb C$ is an $\mathbb R$-albebra with basis $\{1,i\}$, so we can split all the complex values up in real/imaginary parts, which doubles the dimension. (3) Just take two general elements and check the definition of homomorphism.

Comment: It is not clear to me why it is legal to writour matrices as coloumn vectors of the matrix that you found its determinant ... could you clarify please?

Comment: Each column is the representation of one of the matrices when viewed as a vector over the basis $\mathscr B$. Remember I view $M_2(\mathbb C)$ as a vector space with $\mathscr B$ as a basis, so the matrices are vectors in that vector space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121053/discussion-between-milten-and-mathmusic).